# mongodb findOne in Object

Tags: mongodb, object

I have been trying to use the MongoDB findOne method but I don't know how use it. The problem is that I have a shema:

```
const CartSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user_id: { type: String },
    products: [{
        prod_id: { type: String },
        qty: { type: Number }
    }]
});
```

And this is my query:

```
ShoppingCart.findOne(
    { $and: [
       { user_id: Item.idUser },
       { products: [{ prod_id: Item.idProd }] }  // my problem is here
    ] },
    callback    
);
```

I need to find this data within the {products} object but and I don't know how to refer to this position

Comment: Also see [Query an Array of Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/) in the core documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `$elemMatch` for this. For example

```
   ShoppingCart.findOne(
{ $and: [
   { user_id: Item.idUser },
   { products:  {$elemMatch : {prod_id : "ID"}} }
] },
callback    
);
```

Read more about it [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

Comment: Thank you. You are a genius. It's working now

Comment: I've added link. You must read about it to have a firm understanding. 
ps. Consider accepting this answer if this resolved your query

Comment: @IanPhill This is not actually "strictly" correct. For a **single** value to match in an array you can simply use "dot notation" to represent the element `ShoppingCart.findOne({ user_id: Item.idUser, "products.prod_id": "ID" }, ...` The `$elemMatch` operator is for "multiple" conditions, i.e `ShoppingCart.findOne({ user_id: Item.idUser, products: { $elemMatch: { prod_id": "ID", qty: { $gt: 1 } } } }, ...`. Also `$and` is rarely needed, and is basically implied of ALL query conditions. Just so you **both** know.